# MySQL - Server Fault When Inserting BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

In my PHP application, users can choose to upload a file and this file will be stored in a table in my MySQL database.

On my XAMPP on Windows instance, this works fine. However, on AWS EC2 Ubuntu, when the form is submitted with a selected file, the web browser comes up with ***"Server Error 500 The website encountered an error while retrieving. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."***

I initially checked the `my.cnf` file for the `max_allowed_packet` size, but this seems to fine as it was at default set to 16MB, however I have a feeling it's do with the Apache server itself not liking the upload of BLOBs.

Here is the PHP code that deals with inserting BLOBs to the table:

```
//execute stored proc. to upload attachment
$null = null;

$query = $this->connection->prepare("CALL sp_PopulateAbstractAttachments(?,?,?,?,?)");
$query->bind_param("ibssi", $abstractID, $null, $name, $type, $size) or die(mysqli_error($this->connection));
foreach (str_split($attachment, 10240) as $chunk)
{
   $query->send_long_data(1, $chunk);
}

$query->execute() or die(mysqli_error($this->connection));

$query->close();
```

Like I said, this works perfectly fine on XAMPP Windows, but not on AWS EC2 Ubuntu. What could be causing this issue?

**EDIT**

According to Apache's error log, this is the problem:

> [Thu Jan 07 19:24:24.571319 2016] [:error] [pid 12049] [client
>   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/models/Abstracts.php
>   on line 40, referer:
>   http://XXXXXXXXXXX/public/index.php?url=home/submitAbstract/

What could the issue be?

Comment: You might need to increase the max_execution_time inside the php script itself. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php for reference.

Comment: Error 500 doesn't tells us much. I suggest getting more info about your error in Ubuntu's server (apache2?)

Comment: @RodolfoAndrade Would you know how I could do that through SSH Client, as that's the only form of interaction I have with the server and I don't know Linux, unfortunately? Yes, it's apache2.

Comment: @DerekPollard I will have a look into that.

Comment: @RodolfoAndrade I found the error, please see post edit.

Comment: Try checking the following file: `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. You might need to `sudo`

Comment: @RodolfoAndrade I found the error, please see. Apparently it's saying that `$this->connection->prepare("...")` might be returning `false` as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17431062/2915050

Comment: add: `if(false === $query) die($this->connection->error);`

This should print your `prepare` call error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100084/discussion-between-rodolfo-andrade-and-royalswish).

Answer (score 0):

hi here you can a little example

```
 if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) 
  { 
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

      $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'rb'); // read binary
  } 

  try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO images ( picture ) VALUES ( ? )");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $conn->errorInfo();
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
    }
```

for more information please check this link and find a example

[insert with pdo php mysql blob](http://www.it-iss.com/mysql/mysql-pdo-inserting-blobs-and-reading/)

please try and good luck